# Mapping ellipse points in space to a 2D plane

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

Good day to all! My task is as follows: there is an array of points in space that form an ellipse, and this array must be designed on a 2D image (as if we were getting an image from a camera). My problem is that in some cases, instead of an ellipse, I can get a hyperbola, which is not good. How to avoid such cases? I do the mapping in the matlab as follows:

```
function [u,v] = point2camProjection(point,f,Oc)
  
  K = [f,0,Oc(1);0,f,Oc(2);0,0,1];
  
  UVW = K*point;
  u=UVW(1)/UVW(3);
  v=UVW(2)/UVW(3); 
end
```

point is the coordinates of the 3D point, f is the focal length of the camera, and Oc is the optical center of the camera.

Comment: Can you provide a combination of inputs that results in a hyperbola, and one that doesn't?

Comment: The fact is that this is part of a composite task. The points of the ellipse are obtained as the points of contact of the cone with the ellipsoid. I.e., the position of the vertex of this cone, which is the position of the camera, changes. Plus the orientation of the camera's coordinate system. It will be difficult for me to provide the data, because it depends on the full implementation of the program.